# Do I need to "Embed" Standard Frameworks such as AdSupport.framework?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode11, xcode11.4

I have added the AdSupport.framework to my XCode project with "Do Not Embed" to use with Firebase Analytics. This was done under the prior knowledge that standard iOS frameworks are already present on iOS devices, thus I would not have to set it to "Embed Without Signing".

However, the data seems to not be pulled through in Firebase.

Do I have to set the framework to "Embed Without Signing" or is "Do Not Embed" the correct approach?

Comment: Was super curious - did you ever solve this? I have the same